# Norm-attaining operators with values in a 2-dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

> Is the set $N\!A(X,\ell_2^2)$ of norm-attaining operators from a Banach space $X$ onto the $2$-dimensional Hilbert space $\ell^2_2$ dense in the Banach space $L(X,\ell_2^2)$ of all linear continuous operators from $X$ to $\ell^2_2$? Is $N\!A(X,\ell^2_2)$ nontrivially nonempty, i.e., is there a surjective norm-attaining operator from $X$ to $\ell_2^2$?

The problem was posed on 29.06.2019 by Dirk Werner (Berlin) on page [137](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=137) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

Comment: Have a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08272

Some new sufficient conditions were obtained there.

Comment: It seems to me that $NA(X, \ell^2_2)$ is always nontrivial: just take a norm-attaining linear functional on $X$ (using Hahn-Banach) and multiply it by a nonzero vector in $\ell^2_2$.

Comment: Checking the original question in the Lviv book I see that the existence part refers to ONTO maps.  Therefore my previous example does not stand.

Comment: @Ruy Thank you for your comment. I corrected "to" to "onto" in the formulation of the question.

Comment: My comment referred to the last occurrence of "to", rather than the first.  It is my impression that the density question still regards all (not necessarily onto) norm attaining operators.

Comment: @Ruy I see that Dirk Werner himself has already edited this question in correct way. Concerning the density problem, it seems that the space of non-surjective operators is closed and nowhere dense in the space of all operators from $X$ to $\ell^2_2$. Isn't it? So, the density of $NA(X,\ell^2_2)$ can be witnessed only by surjective opeartors.

Comment: I get it.  It is indeed a subtle point.  Thanks!

Comment: Since $\ell_2^2$ is finite dimensional, I think the set of all non-surjective operators is in fact closed with empty interior!